# ¿Si tengo una Consulta SQL tal usando WITH(CTE) puedo obtener los mismos resultados sin ella?

Tags: sql, db2

Estaba realizando una vista que hace uso de WITH, y resulta que el ClienteWeb Compiere no se lleva bien con las vistas con WITH..(me comentaron)

Entonces quería saber si puedo llegar a los mismos resultados en los datos sin usar WITH.

Si tienen algún ejemplo, o si no se puede y porque, les agradecería!

**Como lo solicitaron aquí la linda consulta de ejemplo**: (esta consulta esta funcional, se puede usar en BIRT, recuerden que en los simbolos '?' van los parametros(valores)...

Sin embargo, para trabajarla dentro del Compiere no me sirve. :(

```
WITH ASIGNADOS AS(
SELECT CC.X_RolConteo_ID, CC.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID
FROM M_ABCAnalysisGroup A
INNER JOIN M_ABCRank R ON (A.M_ABCAnalysisGroup_ID = R.M_ABCAnalysisGroup_ID)
INNER JOIN M_ABCProductAssignment PA ON (R.M_ABCRank_ID = PA.M_ABCRank_ID)
INNER JOIN XX_CN_ABCProductCycleCounting CC ON (CC.M_ABCProductAssignment_ID = PA.M_ABCProductAssignment_ID)
WHERE R.M_ABCRank_ID = ?
AND CC.X_RolConteo_ID IS NOT NULL 
AND CC.X_RolConteo_ID != 100
GROUP BY CC.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID, CC.X_RolConteo_ID
),
CONTADOS AS(
SELECT CC.X_RolConteo_ID, CC.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID
FROM M_ABCAnalysisGroup A
INNER JOIN M_ABCRank R ON (A.M_ABCAnalysisGroup_ID = R.M_ABCAnalysisGroup_ID)
INNER JOIN M_ABCProductAssignment PA ON (R.M_ABCRank_ID = PA.M_ABCRank_ID)
INNER JOIN XX_CN_ABCProductCycleCounting CC ON (CC.M_ABCProductAssignment_ID = PA.M_ABCProductAssignment_ID)
WHERE R.M_ABCRank_ID = ?
AND CC.X_RolConteo_ID IS NOT NULL 
AND CC.X_RolConteo_ID != 100
AND PA.ISCOUNTED = 'Y'
GROUP BY CC.X_RolConteo_ID, CC.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID
)
SELECT  
RC.X_RolConteo_ID,
BP.NAME||' - #'|| BP.ficha BPNameFicha,
OSZL.X_OrgSubZonaLINE_ID,
SZ.Name SubZonaName,
SZ.Name||' '||OSZL.LOCATORVALUE SUBZONA,
CASE WHEN UPPER(OSZL.LOCATORVALUE) = LOWER (OSZL.LOCATORVALUE) THEN INTEGER(OSZL.LOCATORVALUE) ELSE 0 END AS SUBZONA_NUM,
CASE WHEN UPPER(OSZL.LOCATORVALUE) != LOWER (OSZL.LOCATORVALUE) THEN OSZL.LOCATORVALUE ELSE '' END AS SUBZONA_STR,
COUNT(OSZE.X_OrgSubZonaElement_ID) CANT_ELEMENTOS,
COUNT (A.X_OrgSubZonaElement_ID) CANT_ASIG,
COUNT (C.X_OrgSubZonaElement_ID) CANT_CONT
FROM X_OrgSubZonaLine OSZL
INNER JOIN X_OrgSubZonaElement OSZE ON (OSZL.X_OrgSubZonaLINE_ID = OSZE.X_OrgSubZonaLINE_ID)
INNER JOIN X_OrgSubZona OSZ ON (OSZL.X_OrgSubZona_ID = OSZ.X_OrgSubZona_ID)
INNER JOIN X_OrgElement OE ON (OSZE.X_OrgElement_ID = OE.X_OrgElement_ID AND OSZ.X_OrgSubZona_ID = OE.X_OrgSubZona_ID)
INNER JOIN X_Subzona SZ ON (OSZ.X_Subzona_ID = SZ.X_Subzona_ID)
INNER JOIN X_Element E ON (OE.X_Element_ID = E.X_Element_ID)

LEFT JOIN ASIGNADOS A ON (OSZE.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID = A.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID)
LEFT JOIN CONTADOS C ON (OSZE.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID = C.X_OrgSubZonaELEMENT_ID)

INNER JOIN X_RolConteo RC ON (A.X_RolConteo_ID = RC.X_RolConteo_ID)
LEFT JOIN C_BPARTNER BP ON (RC.C_BPARTNER_ID = BP.C_BPARTNER_ID)
WHERE OSZL.AD_ORG_ID = ?
GROUP BY RC.X_RolConteo_ID, OSZL.X_OrgSubZonaLINE_ID, 
OSZL.LOCATORVALUE,
SZ.Name,OSZL.LOCATORVALUE, BP.NAME, BP.ficha
ORDER BY BP.NAME, SZ.NAME, SUBZONA_NUM, SUBZONA_STR
```

A cosa importante.. lo que muestro en el reporte es: 
Nombre del trabajador
Subzona(en la que esta realizando el conteo - "ubicación" ) 
Elementos Asignados (cantidad de elementos en la cuenta de productos asignados a un trabajador)
Elementos Contados (cantidad de productos contados)
el % avanzado... 
y los totales de los asignados, contados y avance. 
pero en este el BIRT lo hace solo, en este caso tendría que meter el calculo dentro de la consulta sql..

Comment: Seria bueno si puedes colocar un ejemplo y en base a eso te proponer una respuesta. Si bien se podria obtener el mismo resultado, las CTE estan para ayudarnos a escribir SQL mas "entendible" y mas aun cuando se utiliza para recursividad. Pero a veces es mas largo o hay que pensarlo de otra manera para obtener los mismos datos. De hecho hemos sobrevivido en versiones anteriores del SQL

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no es muy complicado este cambio...

Supongamos este Query:

```
CREATE VIEW V_TOTAL_VENTAS(    SUC_CODIGO,    VENTAS2011,    VENTAS2012) AS
     WITH TotalVentasAnuales AS (
      SELECT
         MVC_CODSUC,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MVC_FECHAX) AS Ano,
         SUM(MVC_TOTALX * MVC_COTIZA) AS VentasAnuales
      FROM
         MOVIMCAB
      GROUP BY
         1, 2    )
     SELECT
      S.SUC_CODIGO,
      V2011.VENTASANUALES AS VENTAS2011,
      V2012.VENTASANUALES AS VENTAS2012    FROM
      SUCURSALES S    LEFT JOIN
      TotalVentasAnuales V2011
         ON S.SUC_CODIGO = V2011.MVC_CODSUC AND
            V2011.Ano = 2011    LEFT JOIN
      TotalVentasAnuales V2012
         ON S.SUC_CODIGO = V2012.MVC_CODSUC AND
            V2012.Ano = 2012;
```

Ahora vez una vista con WITH, y no nos sirve por según tu con lo que trabajas no le gustan los CTE...  oooww.. PERO NO HAY PROBLEMA!

Vemos que la CTE (WITH) `TotalVentasAnuales` abreviado "V2012" es llamada por un `LEFT JOIN`, bien ahora c**ambiamos TotalVentasAnuales** por un `AS`, si y ahora despues del `left join` colocamos la consulta interna del `WITH`, y ya nos deshacemos de nuestro amigo!! :) aquí va:

```
SELECT
      S.SUC_CODIGO,
      V2011.VENTASANUALES AS VENTAS2011,
      V2012.VENTASANUALES AS VENTAS2012    FROM
      SUCURSALES S    LEFT JOIN
      (
       SELECT
         MVC_CODSUC,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MVC_FECHAX) AS Ano,
         SUM(MVC_TOTALX * MVC_COTIZA) AS VentasAnuales
      FROM
         MOVIMCAB
      GROUP BY 1, 2
      )
        AS V2011 ON S.SUC_CODIGO = V2011.MVC_CODSUC AND V2011.Ano = 2011 
        LEFT JOIN TotalVentasAnuales V2012
        ON S.SUC_CODIGO = V2012.MVC_CODSUC AND V2012.Ano = 2012;
```

Intenta seguir estos pasos y prueba con tus tablas! creo que lo puse entendible para cualquier caso, lo ultimo que tendrías que hacer seria ver que campos extra necesitaría Compiere para generar la tabla (vista) que te ayudara a crear la ventana ...

Te recomiendo estos links son verdaderos tesoros de la web (stack.. seria el planeta del tesoro XD jeje):

https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/SQL-Server-Expresiones-de-tabla-comunes.aspx

https://firebird21.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/usando-cte-common-table-expression/

https://firebird21.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/usando-una-subconsulta-en-un-join/